# Are there any HTTP Live Streaming clients for Windows?

Tags: windows, client, vlc, http-live-streaming

Is there a Windows player that implements the client portion of [the HTTP Live Streaming RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-04)? This would be quite handy for testing purposes.

A VLC nightly (1.2.0-git-20100811) can open some of the [sample m38u playlists provided by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-DontLinkElementID_22), but it treats each segment as a separate video, so I don't think VLC trunk has a full client implementation yet. Any alternatives?

Comment: Just tried XBMC 9.11 - I can confirm that it does not correctly interpret the HTTP Live Streaming extensions to the m3u playlist format.

Answer (score 2):

Try VLC 0.8.4 on the server and on the client sides.  I used this to capture my TV programme through a satellite box on to my laptop running VLC 0.8.4 and then stream to the internet.  On another Laptop somewhere in the world (actually i used this second laptop when I go to work) to receive the live streaming video in real-time.  It is wonderful.  I enjoy my lovely programmes on the go with laptop.  My next finding is to receive it on my Blackberry bold.

Comment: That isn't HLS, it's just http streaming.

Answer (score 2):

Some possible clients are [VLC from the 1.2 branch](http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/win32/branch-/) (or the demo from [Anevia](http://demo.anevia.com:8080/ott/vlc.php)), [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/), [Boxee](http://www.boxee.tv/download#pc), [ffplay](http://ffmpeg.org/)/[avplay](http://libav.org/).

Comment: Unfortunately, the nightly build for VLC 1.2.x is currently broken as far as HLS goes. It seems to be an issue with the generation of filenames for the segmented video streams.

Comment: Its working great in 2.0.6 - I'm using it to publish an HLS in 3 simultaneous bandwidths using both the Windows and OSX versions of VLC. VLC clients on Windows and OSX also receive and play the streams successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The free 3ivx HLS Media Player for Windows 8 in the Windows Store can play m3u8 HLS URLs

http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/3ivx-hls-player/f79ce7d0-2993-4658-bc4e-83dc182a0614

Answer (score 1):

- [Microsoft Media Platform Player Framework](https://playerframework.codeplex.com/) should support HLS as well.
- [LAV Filters](https://github.com/nevcairiel/lavfilters) can read HLS, too. So just install LAV filters (e.g. K-Lite Codec Pack) and you should be able to play HLS in any Windows video player. I have tried MPC-HC and it playe HLS fine.
- [See the Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming#Clients).

Answer (score 0):

itunes perhaps?

Comment: Good thought. However, as far as I can tell neither iTunes 9.2.1.5 nor Quicktime 7.6.6 (latest Windows versions at time of writing) can read Apple's sample HTTP Live Streaming playlists correctly.

Answer (score 0):

VLC version 2.1.5 "Ricewind" plays HLS streams.  I have tried myself.  It is not the best as it has moves between the bit rates but if you keep constant bandwidth it works fine.